# Using unless stated otherwise in references

Tags: reference, unless

I have to write a reference section where most of the figures are from one source. However, the other few left are to be referenced. I am planning to write something like "All tables and figures are from _____ unless stated otherwise".

I am confused about whether I should put the references for other figures before or after this statement.

Comment: Surely the citations for the exceptions would come immediately after any specific figure that didn't come from the same source as the general reference. (Just as any citation normally does.) Or am I misunderstanding something about the question?

Comment: @jason bassford I don’t understand. Aren’t the figures”that didn’t come from the same source as the general reference” the exceptions in the first place?So should I put the statement for the general reference before or after list of the references for all the exceptions?

Comment: All figures and tables, unless stated otherwise, are from respective research papers
• Desert Rain video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMeW5snKvtI
• Mona Lisa, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa
• Guernica, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernica_(Picasso)
• Fountain, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_(Duchamp)
• La Bais-ô-Drôme, https://www.ateliervanlieshout.com/work/la-bais-drme/

In the above the example, is the first line rightly placed or should it be placed at the end of the list

Comment: Your last comment doesn't match what you asked in the question. Saying **from one source** means something completely different than **from respective research papers**. But saying that, there is no need for that sentence *at all* if each figure has its own unique citation. Just provide the figures and cite each as you normally would. (A superscript number after each figure title, and the reference in an endnote.)

Comment: @jason bassford Oh that was my mistake. It’s just one source. Anyways I got your point.